# Laravel form throwing Method Exception error (Checked Post everywhere)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade

```
<form id="searchForm"  action="searchProduct" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                  <input type="text" id="wholeProdSearch" name="searchProd" placeholder="Search" class="wholeProdSearch">
                   <i class="search link icon"></i>
               </form>
```

I have the form... I tried to search something when user clicks enter..
here's the js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input.wholeProdSearch').on( 'keypress', function (e) {
         if (e.which == 13) {
          $('#searchForm').submit();
        }
      });
  });
```

I have this route

```
Route::post('searchProduct','Retailer\ProductController@searchProduct');
```

And still its throwing me error on  method exception...works well with get method..but when I try this..it's still throwing me error

error is

```
**MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 207:**
in RouteCollection.php line 207
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 194
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 142
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 729
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 652
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 628
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 214
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 141
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 43
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 17
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 55
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 61
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 36
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 40
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 125
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 101
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 115
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 84
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Comment: try to write your form action like {{ url('/searchProduct') }} i think this will do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to the `action="searchProduct"` property on the form not correctly resolving to a Route Path.

Instead, you should try using the `route()` or `url()` helpers:

```
action="{{ url('/searchProduct') }}"
```

or give your routes a name for clarity:

```
Route::post('searchProduct','Retailer\ProductController@searchProduct')->name('product.search');
```

And then use the `route` helper:

```
action="{{ route('product.search') }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

try to write your form action like

```
{{ url('/searchProduct') }}
```

it will do the trick